# Что быстрее выполнится: вывод на экран или запись в файл?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Python, Jupyter Notebook
Двумерный массив Numpy 10000*10000

Comment: как вы выводите массив на экран?

Comment: использую print(Массив)

Comment: тогда быстрей будет вывод на экран, т.к. Numpy покажет только начальные и конечные строки и столбцы... Пример - выполните в Jupyter Notebook: `print(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 100)))`